# How to constrain a UIImageView to the best size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

In my IOS app I want to display the biggest variation of an image that can be fully displayed on the device.  I want to do it without resizing the image to be larger or smaller so that the image doesn't seem blurry.

On my webserver I have 3 variations of the same image. To keep it simple let's say they only differ in width: 640, 750 and 1000.

An iPhone 5 will display the 640 width image.
An iPhone 6 will display the 750 width image.
An iPhone 6+ will display the 1000 width image.

I can easily get the size of a UIImageView in order to download the right image, but how to do I set an Auto Layout Constraint on the UIImageView that sets the UIImageView to the right width?

If I set a low priority <= 1000 width constraint on the UIImageView, then the image is displayed at a width of 1000 regardless of the size of the device. This is true even when I set the UIImageView to have a low Content Compression Resistance Priority.

I am using XCode, Objective C and IOS 8.

If I'm going about this wrong please tell me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy solution would be to make a width constraint of the UIImageView, then create an outlet for the same.

Now inside the code , set constraint.constant value by calculating according to the device.

Comment: So based on the width of the device i choose the image and then set the image's width constraint programatically? Cool. Is that the normal way?

Comment: In pure autoLayout it will be pretty much head ache...may be the new designing features in xcode 7 will be helpful.  Btw no issues in setting constraints in code.